# How to call a loading spinner within a class

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progress-bar

I am trying to load a "loading spinner" from a class and I am wondering what is the best way to achieve this. In my class there is a Asynch task in which I want the spinner to start and finish. I have created my loading spinner in a layout now what I am trying to do is I want the spinner to be shown while the Asynch task finishes.

Here is my class:

```
public class ClusterManager extends ClusterManager {

public ClusterManager() {
    super();        
}

private void reload() {

    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>()
    {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params)
        {
            //Start spinner here
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid)
        {
            //Stop/Remove the spinner
        }
    }.execute();

}
```

And my Custom spinner

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ProgressBar
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/LoadingSpinner"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

</ProgressBar>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can load a ProgressDialog in the constructor of the class and show it of hide it in the two callbacks.

Another alternative is to pass a listener from the activity or fragment and behing notify when to show or hide. In this way you can have to progress bar in your layout.

Comment: Yeah but in My case I am using a  spinner not a progress dialog. I just what to show a circle that spins around but I am not sure how to load it :/

Comment: In doInBackground you cannot show the spinner anyway because you cannot touch ui, so you have to use on pre execute. That said there is no way to load the view from the AsyncTask you should either pass the view in the contructor or use a listener.

Comment: What if I inflate the layout of the spinner inside the class and close it in omPostExcute.

Comment: you should pass a context to the Task